# Resize logo to menu in CSS?

Tags: html, css

What should I change in CSS to match logo size to menu. I tried do it myself but I can't do it.
http://marekzurek.com

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You start by reading [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following CSS:

```css
.logo img {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  height: 80px;
}

.menu-bg .logo {
  padding-top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Is anyway to make menu in middle?
http://i.imgur.com/CVZ2O2i.png

Comment: changed padding top from 10px to 15px. Please click on the check mark on the left of the answer to close the question. Thanks

Comment: I will do. Now is ok but when you scroll down there is animation: menu goes up, logo goes down. What should I do to logo goes up in the same time like menu?

Comment: change the .menu-bg .logo padding-top to 10px. This should solve all of your issues. Please note that I have also edited .logo padding-top and it is not 15px instead of 10px

Answer (score 2):

```css
.menu-bg img {
    max-height: 120px;
}
```